# I'm getting a ParseError in nodejs and with a really not proper error message

Tags: node.js

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Error (native)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:317:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

What can be the possible cause of this error? And where can I put the try-catch or fun(err) for error handling! I'm even not getting the source of this error, what can be the possible source of this error?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make an HTTP request and the server is sending an invalid HTTP response.

Comment: So what do you propose to handle this error? Can you share a code fragment on this error handling for me to try out?

Answer (score 3):

I got a very similar stack trace when running gulp as a proxy.

```
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
```

I found the root cause after a while.

The backend server was sending duplicate headers due to a bug in the backend. By removing the duplicate HTTP header This error in the javascript frontend was fixed.

Example of duplicate http headers (for example content-length):

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: Cowboy
< date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 12:47:15 GMT
< content-length: 4789
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 4789
< date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 12:47:14 GMT
< server: Cowboy
```

Comment: Hello! I'm very glad that i have came across on your question. I have same problem now. HTTP Requests finish with error "Parse error". I saw request with curl and it showed me two same headers. How could you have deleted  this same headers?

Comment: @Semerkin: I do not know how to remove duplicate http headers in javascript. The "proper" solution is to fix the backend so that it never does send duplicate headers. I hope you can fix the backend yourself or report an issue to the one responsible for your backend.

Answer (score 2):

Without any code I can only guess to the specific reason, but it looks like you're trying to make an HTTP request to a server that is returning an invalid HTTP response.

To catch these errors, use an `error` event handler on your client (provided that you're using the `http` module):

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(URL, function(response) { ... }).on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err); // or however you want to deal with it
});
```

Comment: This helped to get a good insight on error! I'm trying to make a work around!

Comment: I'm able to now print the error as follows: function next(err) { if (err && err === 'route') { return done(); } var layer = stack[idx++]; if (!layer) { return done(err); } if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) { return next(err); } if (err) { layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next); } else { layer.handle_request(req, res, next); } }
     
err.stack gives "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not listening to errors at all. Try as it follows:

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.on('error', function(err) {
        // here you can handle errors on the response
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    // here you can handle errors on the request
});
```

This way you can catch the error and try to understand what's happening.
Nobody can say why you are receiving a parse error with the data provided till now.

Comment: I'm able to now print the error as follows: 
    function next(err) {
        if (err && err === 'route') {
          return done();
        }

        var layer = stack[idx++];
        if (!layer) {
          return done(err);
        }

        if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) {
          return next(err);
        }

        if (err) {
          layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next);
        } else {
          layer.handle_request(req, res, next);
        }
      }

Comment: err.stack gives "undefined"